# How to insert date and time using short cut keys in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I insert `Date` and `Time` in `MS Word` using short cut key.

As I can using `=TODAY(), = =NOW(), =DATE()` and other such type used in `MS EXCEL`,  so What is way to insert such things in `MS Word`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date:** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

**Time:** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>